# Android NDK / MediaPlayer - Customer player logging C2DColorConvert

Tags: android-ndk, media-player, android-mediacodec, qualcomm

I have VR video player that is built (C++, shared library) using Android NDK's Media API (mediandk, OpenSLES, EGL etc.). Player works as expected but one issue that I have is that in logcat, I see lot of messages as below: `C2DColorConvert: unknown format passed for luma alignment number`

This is running on LG G6/Qualcomm and post decoding of video, images are sent through some post processing and finally rendered on two textures (RGBA32 type) shown inside Unity App.

Any suggestions regarding how to remove above error?

Above error comes from following [file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/qcom/media/+/2a914b33529b826083ff39ec764426680367b157/libc2dcolorconvert/C2DColorConverter.cpp)

`size_t C2DColorConverter::calcLumaAlign(ColorConvertFormat format) {
    if (!isYUVSurface(format)) return 1; //no requirement
    switch (format) {
        case NV12_2K:
          return ALIGN2K;
        default:
          ALOGE("unknown format passed for luma alignment number");
          return 1;
    }
}`

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: @sinek - no this is not resolved.